# heroku startup "error loading plugin commands", "heroku local web" fails

Tags: heroku

OK I fixed the problem. It is failing because it is trying to rename to an existing file, once I deleted the file it was able to proceed installing the plugins and now everything is fine.

Trying to get started with Node.js on Heroku. I really don't think I can add any more details than the commands and output, but the site won't let me post unless I add more verbiage.

```
PS C:\Users\adamk\heroku\node-js-getting-started> heroku local web
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done.
For more information on Toolbelt v4: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli
Setting up node-v4.1.1... ▸    rename C:\Users\adamk\.heroku\tmp\download455882471\file C:\Users\adamk\.heroku\node-v4.1
.1-windows-x86\bin\node.exe: Access is denied.
error loading plugin commands
error loading plugin topics
error loading plugin commands
 !    `local` is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant `lock`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.

PS C:\Users\adamk\heroku\node-js-getting-started> heroku plugins
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done.
For more information on Toolbelt v4: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli
Setting up node-v4.1.1... ▸    rename C:\Users\adamk\.heroku\tmp\download156546799\file C:\Users\adamk\.heroku\node-v4.1
.1-windows-x86\bin\node.exe: Access is denied.
error loading plugin commands
error loading plugin topics
error loading plugin commands
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       No such file or directory - "C:/Users/adamk/.heroku/heroku-cli.exe" plugins (Errno::ENOENT)
    Command:     heroku plugins
    Version:     heroku/toolbelt/3.42.3 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
    Error ID:    65ccb27b99e8450aba316ff617b544c0


    More information in C:/Users/adamk/.heroku/error.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I fixed the problem. It is failing because it is trying to rename to an existing file, once I deleted the file it was able to proceed installing the plugins and now everything is fine.

Comment: Just to clarify... this works but I had to delete the entire `/node-v4.1.1-windows-x86` folder, not just the files in `/heroku/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

Heroku toolbelt does not have permission to write to the *.heroku* folder on your machine. You can try using *sudo* but I would suggest you *chown* the home folder for your user to run it without using *sudo*

Comment: I am running on Windows. As far as I can tell, this directory is writeable by everyone. (Or maybe I am mistaken, a reminder for how to check might help.)

Comment: Sorry, I completely overlooked the path. I would've noticed that you were on Windows. But the issue is the same on Windows. You do not have write permissions to that folder. Try uninstalling and installing the toolbelt as an **Administrator**  by right-clicking on the installer and selecting *Run As Administrator*

Comment: OK I tried that, same problem. The file C:\Users\adamk\.heroku\node-v4.1.1-windows-x86\bin\node.exe already exists, I think it is getting the Access denied error because it is trying to rename to an existing file.